# Confusion about Convex Functions

Tags: calculus, functions, convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

I was studying Inequalities when I came across Jensen Inequality

It is applied to convex function and the inequality is flipped when applied to concave functions

I read from different sources but I wasn't able to add up convex and concave functions

Can anyone help me out here ?

BTW if possible please present your answer in simple language ( and terms)

Comment: Sorry for the strange format

Comment: Concave function is not really used so much. Most authors use the terms convex and nonconvex functions, rather than concave.

Comment: @TonyS.F.  Thank you for the correction

Comment: @TonyS.F. If you are implying that *concave* and *non-convex* are the same, then I disagree.

Comment: Before your edit, your question said "concave" rather than "non-convex".  These two terms aren't synonyms.  I think "concave" was more likely what you really meant.  A function $f$ is concave iff $-f$ is convex.

Comment: What do you not understand about [convex/concave functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) as explained on Wikipedia? This is important information for us in order to help you. Or is your question actually about this specific connection between convexity and Jensen's inequality? Do you know what convex shapes/sets are?

Comment: @littleO I guess we're having a conflict between non convex and concave

Comment: "Non-convex" just means "not convex", it certainly does not mean the same thing as concave. The question made more sense before the edit.

Comment: @M.Winter  what does convex set mean

Comment: Please use web search first and most of your questions can be answered: the page on [convex sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) has  very nice and intuitive pictures, even for convex functions. If this is not helping then specifically point out what you not understand.

Comment: @M.Winter Got it . I really didn't pay attention to 'convex set' . Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @M.Winter No I am not implying that but I see now that my wording was especially misleading, sorry about that. I was doubtful that concavity was what the OP was actually looking for, suggesting that maybe they meant to write nonconvex, but they're certainly different notions, I agree. I should have wrote, "Most authors are more concerned with convex and non convex rather than concave."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f$ is convex if, given any two points $A \,(a, f(a))$ and $B\,(b,f(b))$ on the representative curve of $f$, the arc of curve from $A$
to $B$ is beneath the chord $[AB]$.? Parametrizing numbers between $a$ and $b$, we see that numerically, this means that
$$\forall t, 0\le t\le 1,\enspace f(at+(1-t)b)\le tf(a)+(1-t)f(b).$$

As this parametrisation amounts to consider a number between $a$ and $b$ as a barycenter of $a$ and $b$ with positive weights, *Jensen's inequality* is just a generalisation to the case of a barycenter of $n$ numbers, and we can describe convex functions as ‘*subbarycentric*’, or ‘*subaffine*’, since affine functions are those functions which preserve barycenters.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ named a convex function if for all $a<b$ and for all $x\in[a,b]$ the point $C(x,f(x))$ is placed under point $D(x,y)$, where $D\in AB$, $A(a,f(a))$, $B(b,f(b)).$

If $f$ is a convex function then for all $\alpha_i\geq0$ such that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n=1$ and for all $x_i$ we have:
$$\alpha_1f(x_1)+\alpha_2f(x_2)+...+\alpha_nf(x_n)\geq f(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+...+\alpha_nx_n).$$

Comment: This here is the Jensen Inequalitiy , I asked for an explanation for a convex function

Comment: @Samyak Jha I added something. See now.

Comment: thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: @Samyak Jha You are welcome!